# Programmatically select mat-tab in Angular 2 material using mat-tab-group

Tags: angular, angular-material

How can I select a specific tab when an event occurs?

I tried with `[selectedIndex]="selectedTab"` changing the `selectedTab` to the tab index needed but it doesn't seems to work after the tabs are loaded.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

**UPDATE (using newest angular+material)**

there are multiple ways..

1. possible solution, using two-way databinding

```html
<button mat-raised-button (click)="demo1BtnClick()">Tab Demo 1!</button>
<mat-tab-group [(selectedIndex)]="demo1TabIndex">
    <mat-tab label="Tab 1">Content 1</mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Tab 2">Content 2</mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Tab 3">Content 3</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

```js
public demo1TabIndex = 1;
public demo1BtnClick() {
  const tabCount = 3;
  this.demo1TabIndex = (this.demo1TabIndex + 1) % tabCount;
}
```

2. possible solution, using template-variable and pass through our click-function

```html
<button mat-raised-button (click)="demo2BtnClick(demo2tab)">Tab Demo 2!</button>
<mat-tab-group #demo2tab>
    <mat-tab label="Tab 1">Content 1</mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Tab 2">Content 2</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

```js
public demo2BtnClick(tabGroup: MatTabGroup) {
  if (!tabGroup || !(tabGroup instanceof MatTabGroup)) return;

  const tabCount = tabGroup._tabs.length;
  tabGroup.selectedIndex = (tabGroup.selectedIndex + 1) % tabCount;
}
```

3. possible solution, using @ViewChild

```html
<button mat-raised-button (click)="demo3BtnClick()">Tab Demo 3!</button>
<mat-tab-group #demo3Tab>
    <mat-tab label="Tab 1">Content 1</mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Tab 2">Content 2</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

```js
@ViewChild("demo3Tab", { static: false }) demo3Tab: MatTabGroup;

public demo3BtnClick() {
  const tabGroup = this.demo3Tab;
  if (!tabGroup || !(tabGroup instanceof MatTabGroup)) return;

  const tabCount = tabGroup._tabs.length;
  tabGroup.selectedIndex = (tabGroup.selectedIndex + 1) % tabCount;
}
```

live-demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-selecting-mattab?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: This worked for me only once. Use `[(selectedIndex)]` for two way binding.

Comment: I had to mix solution 1 and 3 to have a good behaviour. Thanks.

Comment: I implemented #1 to trigger two tabs, one tab for login and one tab for register.  To programmatically trigger the register tab, from a link that says, "no account? create account" - it works.  Thanks!  Although I had my link as a child component and had to trigger via eventEmitter.  Works like charm still.

Comment: @Mathias Thank you for the idea of using `[(selectedIndex)] ` for two way binding. It helped me greatly.

Answer (score 37):

In case it helps anyone, it is also possible to set `selectedIndex` on the MatTabGroup in your component.

If your HTML has: `<mat-tab-group #tabs>`, you can get a reference to it in the component using `@ViewChild('tabs') tabGroup: MatTabGroup;`.

Then you can do `this.tabGroup.selectedIndex = newIndex;` in the OnInit function, or elsewhere.

Comment: Just to add to this answer: Angular 8 now requires an object with 'static' for ViewChild: `@ViewChild('tabs', {static: false}) tabGroup: MatTabGroup;` and  one needs to import the following: `import { MatTabGroup } from '@angular/material';`

Comment: Had to use `ngAfterContentInit(`) instead of `OnInit()` for lazy loaded content. Angular first needs to "projects external content into the component's view.." and ngAfterContentInit() makes sure it is. See [Angular life cycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks).

Answer (score 9):

I also had similar issue. In my case I needed to show the tab the user was there before he left the component. I solved this by stuffing the current selected tab index in a service.

On HTML template I have this:

```
<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="getSelectedIndex()" (selectedTabChange)="onTabChange($event)">
```

Implementation of onTabChange and getSelectedIndex are as follows:

```
    getSelectedIndex(): number {
        return this.appService.currentTabIndex
    }

    onTabChange(event: MatTabChangeEvent) {
        this.appService.currentTabIndex = event.index
    }
```

My service code looks like this:

```
export class AppService {
    public currentTabIndex = 1  //default tab index is 1
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and I tried the above answers but they are not helping. Here is my solution:

In my typescript code, first, declare a variable:

```
selected = new FormControl(0); // define a FormControl with value 0. Value means index.
```

then, in the function:

```
changeTab() {
    this.selected.setValue(this.selected.value+1);
 } //
```

in the html,

```
 <mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="selected.value" (selectedIndexChange)="selected.setValue($event)">
            <mat-tab label="label0">0</mat-tab>
            <mat-tab label="label1">1</mat-tab>
            <mat-tab label="label2">2</mat-tab>
            <mat-tab label="label3">3</mat-tab>
            <mat-tab label="label4">4</mat-tab>
            <mat-tab label="label5">5</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>

<button (click)="changeTab()">ChangeTab</button>
```

Comment: There is an example for this in the Angular Material docs called "Tab group with dynamically changing tabs": https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/examples

Comment: This is the best option and it's in the official docs above.

Comment: Not sure why but I had to specify index property for $event having: `(selectedTabChange)="selected.setValue($event.index)"`

Comment: @Jordi one year late, but this is because you're using `selectedTabChange` and not `selectedIndexChange`

Answer (score 3):

```html
@Input()selectedIndex: number | null: The index of the active tab.  

SelectedIndex expects a number binding as property, so you can select any tab starting from 0 to (workflow_list.length - 1)

<mat-tab-group class="m-t-30" [selectedIndex]="2">
    <mat-tab label="{{wf.ApproverName}}" *ngFor="let wf of workflow_list">
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Answer (score 2):

**it's worked for me**

```
    isActiveTab = 0 // First tab
    isActiveTab = 1 // Second Tab
        
       <mat-tab-group mat-align-tabs="start" 
         (selectedTabChange)="onTabChanged($event.index)"
          [selectedIndex]="isActiveTab" >
        
         <mat-tab label="One"> </mat-tab>
         <mat-tab label="Two"> </mat-tab>
            
       </mat-tab-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using angular 10 and make my mat-options with ngFor;
in my case no one of the solutions didn't work and finally i found the tabIndex is the index of object in list that we have ngFor on it;

```
<mat-tab-group mat-align-tabs="start" style="width: 100%;text-align: start;overflow: hidden"
                     (selectedTabChange)="setNodeInfo($event)" [(selectedIndex)]="selectedIpIndex">
        <mat-tab *ngFor="let nodeTab of nodeList" [tabIndex]="nodeTab.id">
          <ng-template mat-tab-label>
            <label>{{nodeTab.ip}}</label>
            <mat-icon class="close-btn" style="font-size: medium;z-index: 100" (click)="tabClose(nodeTab)">close
            </mat-icon>
          </ng-template>
        </mat-tab>
      </mat-tab-group>
```

as you see i get the each tabIndex value in html like this:

```
[tabIndex]="nodeTab.id"
```

but it doesn't work and get index of position in list by its own choice.

and in my ts file i fill selectedIpIndex like this :

```
this.selectedIpIndex = this.nodeList.indexOf(node);
```

Answer (score -1):

you could **add a reference to the element that is going to set the Tab index property called `[selectedIndex]`**,
so if you have `<mat-select>` for example do the following:

1. add a local reference to this element like `<mat-select #tabSelection>`.
2. add on the reference value on the mat group element like this: `<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="tabSelection.value">`
3. voila!!, once you change the value the tab will change