# How do I make the browser navigate to a specified tab on button-click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have an mdTabs setup like this:

```
<md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom>
  <md-tab label="The first tab" id="first-tab-wrapper" class="tab-wrapper">
  </md-tab>
  <md-tab label="The second tab" id="second-tab-wrapper" class="tab-wrapper">
  </md-tab>
</md-tabs>
<button>GO TO SECOND TAB</button>
```

When the user clicks the `button`, the browser should go to the second mdTab. How do I do this?

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41937176/programmatically-select-md-tab-in-angular-2-material

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `md-selected` to keep track of the tab:

> Index of the active/selected tab

HTML:

```
<md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom md-selected="selectedTab">
  <md-tab label="The first tab" id="first-tab-wrapper" class="tab-wrapper">
  </md-tab>
  <md-tab label="The second tab" id="second-tab-wrapper" class="tab-wrapper">
  </md-tab>
</md-tabs>
<button ng-click="selectTab()">GO TO SECOND TAB</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.selectTab = function() {
  //go to second tab
  $scope.selectedTab = 1;
}
```