# Is there any way to change activated mat-tab programmatically?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to change activated mat-tab in typescript 
file. Here [Programmatically select md-tab in Angular 2 material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41937176/programmatically-select-md-tab-in-angular-2-material) I found the closest solution but for md-tab not mat-tab.I tried this but didn't work.Here what I tried

**HTML**

```
  <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="changeTab()">Click me!</button>

    <mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="selectedTab">
        <mat-tab label="Preview"> 
    </mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="Tuning">
        <car-tuning></car-tuning>
        </mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="Payment"></mat-tab> 
      </mat-tab-group>
```

**.TS File**

```
 changeTab() {
     this.selectedTab =1;
}
```

Comment: There's [an example on the site showing how to programmatically set the selected tab](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/examples) (fourth one down).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add `two way binding` like this  `[(selectedIndex)]="selectedTab"` and should give you result.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="changeTab()">Click me!</button>

<mat-tab-group [(selectedIndex)]="selectedTab"> //<--- changes
   <mat-tab label="Preview"> 
   </mat-tab>
   <mat-tab label="Tuning">
     <car-tuning></car-tuning>
   </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Payment"></mat-tab> 
</mat-tab-group>
```

In ts:

```
changeTab() {
   this.selectedTab = 1 //<------- your tab value
}
```

Comment: the Bannanabox binding here does the trick. In the Api Examples its not clearly highlighted https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/examples#tab-group-dynamic

Answer (score 2):

yes you can change like this.

```
<mat-tab-group [(selectedIndex)]="selectedIndex">
    <mat-tab>

    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab>

    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab>

    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

In ts use:

```
selectedIndex: number;
```

in your function

```
this.selectedIndex = whateverIndexYouWant;
```

here is how I change activated index from ts.

```
this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(message => {
  switch (message) {
    case 'blabla':
      this.selectedIndex = 0;
      break;
    case 'blablablabla':
      this.selectedIndex = 1;
      break;
    case 'blablablablablabla':
      this.selectedIndex = 2;
      break;
  }
});
```