# How to programmatically grab mat-tab-group's selected Index

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a mat-tab-group with two mat-tabs. When the user clicks submit, I'm trying to figure out which tab is selected. How do I do that?

In my submit method, I want to grab the correct tab so I know which input field to read from. I tried following [Programmatically select mat-tab in Angular 2 material using mat-tab-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41937176/programmatically-select-mat-tab-in-angular-2-material-using-mat-tab-group) but this question is asking something different and I couldn't figure out how to adapt the question to mine.

```
<mat-tab-group mat-align-tabs="center">
      <mat-tab label="Pre-selected Options">
        <mat-card-content>
          <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="center center" fxLayoutGap="20px" class="fnol-min-widht50">
            <div style="  width: 40%;">
              <div *ngIf="!hidden" [ngClass]="[routeAnimationsElements,'add-marging-bottom40']">
                <mat-form-field>
                  <mat-select placeholder="Vested Options" formControlName="vestedoptions" [id]="vestedoptions" mask="" thousandSeparator="">
                    <mat-option selected></mat-option>
                    <mat-option [value]="1">
                      A MARRIED MAN, AS HIS SOLE AND SEPARATE PROPERTY
                    </mat-option>
                    <mat-option [value]="2">
                      A MARRIED WOMAN AND A MARRIED MAN
                    </mat-option>
                    <mat-option [value]="3">
                      A MARRIED WOMAN, AS HER SOLE AND SEPARATE PROPERTY
                    </mat-option>
                    <mat-option [value]="4">
                      A MARRIED WOMAN/MAN AS HER/HIS SOLE AND SEP PROP
                    </mat-option>
                    <mat-option [value]="5">
                      A SINGLE MAN
                    </mat-option>
                    <mat-option [value]="6">
                      A SINGLE MAN AND A SINGLE WOMAN AS JOINT TENANTS
                    </mat-option>
                    <mat-option [value]="7">
                      A SINGLE PERSON
                    </mat-option>
                    <mat-option [value]="8">
                      A SINGLE WOMAN
                    </mat-option>
                    <mat-option [value]="9">
                      A WIDOW
                    </mat-option>
                    <mat-option [value]="10">
                      A WIDOWER
                    </mat-option>
                    <mat-option [value]="11">
                      AN UNMARRIED MAN
                    </mat-option>
                    <mat-option [value]="12">
                      AN UNMARRIED WOMAN
                    </mat-option>
                    <mat-option [value]="13">
                      HUSBAND && WIFE AS COM PROP WITH RIGHT OF SURVIVOR
                    </mat-option>
                    <mat-option [value]="14">
                      HUSBAND AND WIFE AS JOINT TENANTS
                    </mat-option>
                  </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </mat-card-content>
      </mat-tab>
      <mat-tab label="Pre-selected Options">
        <mat-card-content>
          <div [ngClass]="[routeAnimationsElements,'add-marging-bottom40']">
            <mat-form-field>
              <input matInput #input class="uppercase" placeholder="Free Text" formControlName="freetext">
              <mat-error *ngIf="!isFreeTextValid">{{this.freeTextErrorMessage}}</mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
        </mat-card-content>
      </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have different options for that the [MatTabGroup](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api#MatTabGroup) has two events `selectedIndexChange` and `selectedTabChange` that will fire every time the tab is changed so you can remember the current tab or tab index. Then you know it once you submit.

Here is a simple example for this case:

```
<mat-tab-group mat-align-tabs="center" (selectedIndexChange)="onSelectedIndexChange($event)" (selectedTabChange)="onSelectedTabChange($event)">
    <mat-tab label="Pre-selected Options 1">
      
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Pre-selected Options 2">
      
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
<button (click)="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
```

And the code:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  private currentTabIndex = 0;

  public onSelectedIndexChange(tabIndex: number) {
    this.currentTabIndex = tabIndex;
    console.log(`Selected Tab Index: ${tabIndex}`);
  }

  public onSelectedTabChange(matTabChangeEvent: MatTabChangeEvent)  {
    console.log(matTabChangeEvent.tab.textLabel);
  }

  public onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.currentTabIndex);
  }
}
```

Another option is to just get the mat group directly using [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) and then just read the index from it on submit. Here is the code for this sample the template can be the same just without the events.

```
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChild(MatTabGroup) matTabGroup: MatTabGroup;

  public onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.matTabGroup.selectedIndex);
  }
}
```

Here is also a [link to a StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-laddgs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) that includes both implementations.

Comment: My mistake was not importing MatTabGroup.

Comment: my mistake was I was not importing MatTabsGroup. Just MatTabsModule

import {MatTabsModule, MatTabGroup } from '@angular/material/tabs';

i am using v8.3.29 and it appears MatTabChangeEvent is no longer importable from material/tabs.  

This did solve my problem.